# difference in loot between different monsters

Tags: diablo-iii

Since even with `Monster Power 1` all monsters are level 63, is there any difference in loot from different monsters? I'm now talking only about normal, white, monsters(so not elite or unique).

For example: a small spiderling that dies with a single blow and some huge golem that takes me 5 seconds to kill. With any `Monster Power`(except for 0) they are both level 63, but is there any difference in loot that they will possibly drop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in the loot they can drop, but monsters with low HP are less likely to drop loot.  From the [official post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/8770357797#7)

> The chance for the following monsters to drop loot has also been
>   reduced to better match their HP:
>
> By 60% for: Accursed, Betrayed,
>   Blazing Ghouls, Ghouls, Murderous Fiends, Reviled, Savage Fiends, and
>   Vicious Ghouls
>
> By 50% for: Bile Crawlers, Crazed Cultists, Dark Cultists, Dark
>   Zealots, Deranged Cultists, Doom Wraiths, Enraged Zealots, Fallen,
>   Fallen Grunts, Fallen Peons, Fallen Soldiers, Ravenous Dead, Shade
>   Stalkers, Shadow Vermin, Skeletal Crawlers, and Spine Lashers
>
> By 40% for: Dark Moon Clan Impalers, Moon Clan Impalers
>
> By 34% for: Blazing Guardians, Charged Constructs, Chilling
>   Constructs, Frost Guardians, Noxious Guardians, Shock Guardians,
>   Smoldering Constructs. and Toxic Constructs
>
> By 25% for: Brood Hatchlings, Cavern Spiders, Crazed Summoners, Dark
>   Conjurers, Dark Summoners, Dust Shamblers, Fallen, Fallen Grunts,
>   Fallen Peons, Fallen Soldiers, Foul Conjurers, Hungry Corpses,
>   Retching Cadavers, Spiderlings

Comment: thanks. But from that post it looks like `Brood Hatchlings` have higher chance of dropping loot than `Blazing Ghouls`, even though `Brood Hatchlings` are a lot weaker.

Comment: @Novarg Presumably `Brood Hatchlings` were much closer to their target loot rates to start with and so needed a much smaller adjustment to drop rates.